# How to Install TP-Link TL-WN823N V3 driver on Rasperry Pi 1 A+ without internet abilities?

Tags: networking, pi-1

My pi can't connect to the internet without a dongle.  However, the dongle I bought (TP-Link TL-WN823N V3) requires the internet to install its' driver.

https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/tl-wn823n/

I've done my best to read the documentation, but it's rather unclear. Can anyone point me to a single file to download, or a set of commands that don't require the internet?

(https://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/install-wifi takes too long to load on my pc, but even when it did I couldn't see anything useful)

Comment: How are you going to download a "single" file onto the Raspberry Pi if it doesn't have an internet connection?  The TPLink documentation which you linked to tells you how to download and compile the driver for a Raspberry Pi, you need to follow those instructions.

Comment: Its a hen or the egg situation. To compile the kernel module you need to download a lot of required dependencies. My suggestion is find a place where you can connect the RPi with Ethernet and do the compilation of the WiFi dongle.